# Cakephp how to find id by value

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, syntax, cakephp-2.0

How can i write this syntax in CakePHP:

Example:

```
$userID = "SELECT user_id FROM customers WHERE phone = '88888888' ";
```

like:

```
$user = $this->Customer->find('first', array('conditions' => array(
             'Customer.user_id WHERE phone' => '88888888')));
```

I would like to find user_id where the phone number have a specific value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is really basic, you should read the documentation for the [`find()`](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find) function.

```
$user = $this->Customer->find('first',  array(
    // You specify which field(s) you want
    'fields' => array('user_id'),
    // You add the condition(s)
    'conditions' => array('Customer.phone' => '88888888'),
));
```

Comment: Sorry still new, i will try read more about the find() function.

But that condition is it not wrong? 

'conditions' => array('user_id' => '88888888')

Will this not search for user_id => 88888888

i like to find user_id with: 'phonne' => '88888888'

Comment: 'conditions' => array('Customer.phone' => '88888888')

Comment: @sanfly oh you're right! I mixed both properties, ty I'm updating my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use cakephp magic functions here. For example: 
 `$user = $this->Customer->findByPhone('8888888');`